# Make all Gerrit Repositories Read only

Tags: git, gerrit, readonly

I need to find a way to make all Repositories within gerrit "read only", without having to do each one individually.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just set "ALLOW Read" in "refs/*" reference for "Anonymous Users" group (all users signed in or not) or "Registered Users" group (all signed in users) at the "All Projects" project and set "Rights Inherit From" to "All Projects" for all repositories in Gerrit.

To change project permissions go to: Projects > List > Select-the-project > Access

[Here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html) you find more details about permissions.

Comment: Is it necessary to block Push for Anonymous Users in addition?

Comment: No, it's forbidden by default. You just need to set ALLOW Push for the groups you decide to grant permission.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry but I can't because I'm not the OP.

Comment: Sorry @ElpieKay my bad. Luke, the answer worked for you? Could you please accept it?